# Escaping or replacing curly/smart quotes in Twitter widget: Tweet text intent

Tags: twitter, widget, escaping, quotes

I'm using selected/highlighted text by the user to generate the  `intent/tweet?text=` content for the Twitter widget's "Tweet text" function.

It works great **except** when it encounters either opening or closing double/single curly quotes within the element's content: ‘ ’ “ ” (`&#8216; &#8217; &#8220; &#8221;`). When any of those characters is included in the selected text, the entire Tweet text dialog window is blank.

I've tried various javascript methods to search/replace the ASCII codes or the Unicode versions of those but to no avail.

The `escape(text)` method is already being used before the text gets to the Twitter widget, so I'm confused as to why it's choking. In the location bar it shows that these characters are being converted to their Unicode versions like u201C.

What could be causing the Tweet text box to fail on these characters even though it seems to be properly converting them anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that one needs to search/replace the **literal entities** themselves, not ASCII codes nor their Unicode counterparts.

So the solution for using selected text in a Twitter widget text intent is:

`text = text.replace(/“/g, "\'").replace(/”/g, "\'").replace(/‘/g, "\'").replace(/’/g, "\'");`

The entities don't need to be escaped.